# What is the difference between active and passive Digital Footprints?

Tags: privacy

I was learning about [Digital footprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_footprint).

What is the difference between active digital footprints and passive digital footprints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Google search for [`digital footprint active passive`](https://www.google.com/search?q=digital+footprint+active+passive) has lead me to [this article](https://medium.com/@_Sourcr/expanding-your-active-and-passive-digital-footprint-sourcr-528a1a925b3c), which explains the difference:

> - **Active data traces** is what a user leaves intentionally. Facebook, Twitter, blog posts, social network connections, image and video uploads all are among the ways individual’s create active digital footprints for themselves.

> - **Passive data traces** connected to an individual are left by others or gathered through activities that the user does without intent. Website visits and actions, searches and online purchases, online reviews and feedback are among the activities that add passive data traces to your digital footprint.

So in short, active data traces are things you intentionally leave behind. Passive data traces are things you don't intentionally leave behind.